# Addition value several input

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

For example i want addition value two input `20` & `10` and done output in alert but i get in output value `2010` If the i should have this output `30`, how is fix it?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SHjZM/

```
<input type"text" name="ok1" value="20">
<input type"text" name="ok2" value="10">



$('button').live('click', function(){
var val_1 = $('input[name="ok1"]').val();
var val_2 = $('input[name="ok2"]').val();
    var Sum = val_1 + val_2;
    alert(Sum) // in the here output is "2010" i want output "30" as: "20+10=30"
})
```

Comment: Unrelated, but do not use live events unless you really need them. They are less efficient and have a couple of disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert variable to integers before addition

```
var Sum = parseInt(val_1, 10) + parseInt(val_2, 10);
```

Update:

If no radix argument is provided or if it is assigned a value of 0, the function tries to determine the base. If the string starts with a 1-9, it will be parsed as base 10. If the string starts with 0x or 0X it will be parsed as a hexidecimal number. If the string starts with a 0 it will be parsed as an octal number. (Note that just because a number starts with a zero, it does not mean that it is really octal.)

http://devguru.com/Technologies/ecmascript/quickref/parseint.html

Comment: FYI, it's good practice to specify the radix when using parseInt.

Comment: If i remove number `10` in `parseInt`, What happens? (like: `parseInt(val_1)+parseInt(val_1)`)

Comment: Why in here i get output "NaN": http://jsfiddle.net/SHjZM/1/ (just clicked on button)

Comment: @KateWintz because textbox ok1 value is empty.

Comment: Well, i should add this line in code: `if(val_1 == ''){
        val_1 = '0';
    }`. Is that true?

Comment: see this post for checking empty values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502354/textbox-empty-check-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the strings to (decimal) numbers.

```
var Sum = parseFloat(val_1, 10) + parseFloat(10, val_2);
```

Comment: Why not `parseInt`? I'd only use floats if necessary, and in the example integers do the job, too.

Comment: Why in here i get output "NaN": http://jsfiddle.net/SHjZM/1/ (just clicked on button)

Comment: @Kate Wintz - You don't have a number in the first text box.