# How to check if a asp text box is empty or not

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [textbox empty check using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502354/textbox-empty-check-using-javascript)

I have a asp.net button and a asp.net textbox, when I click on button, I want to check if textbox is empty or not but not sure how I can do that,

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEU" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="button" runat="server" OnClientClick="MyFunction(); return false;" ImageUrl="/myfolder/abc.png" />
</div>
```

in my JavaScript I am doing,

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function doWork() 
    {  
        if($input[]
```

**not sure  how to check if its empty or not, if its empty then I am doing something if not then it should call a code behind method for that button.**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty is that question telling how to call a code behind method as well ?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty This link you now posted asking me to have another button that will do a post back which I don't want in my case, I would suggest you to live in positive world with a positive mind you might get somewhere by chance :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read on the [ClientIDMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to see [how element ID are generated](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/08/clientid-mode-in-aspnet-40.html) in ASP.NET (4.0 and above)

```
function doWork() 
{  
     var textbox = document.getElementById('<%=txtEU.ClientID%>');

     if(textbox.value.length == 0)
     {

     }
}
```

OR

```
if(textbox.value == "")
```

Using Validators will help you handle some of this validation out of the box. One of them is [RequiredValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which evaluates the value of an input control to ensure that the user enters a value.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="txtEURequiredValidator" ErrorMessage="EU should not be empty" />
```

Comment: I think the best practice with asp.net is to use the validators.

Comment: I was focusing on the JavaScript challenge accessing controls in asp.net. Updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you have the ability to use a RequiredFieldValidator or a CustomValidator if you need to execute a more complex scenario.

Here is a good starting point i think: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/introduction/
(check the links on the right side to have a detailed view of the validators)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like so:

```
if ($('#<%= txtEU.ClientID %>').val()({
   // String is not empty
}
```

*Explanation:*

- Because, by default, asp.net mangles the html ID for the text box, you will need to inject the name into your jQuery.
- In jQuery, null and empty [can both be tested for with !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812245/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-for-an-empty-string-with-jquery-out-of-the-box)

Answer (score 1):

```
 //javascript code
function Myfunction()
    {   
       if(document .getElementById("<%=txtEU.ClientID %>").value=="")
        {
            alert("Please Enter Text");
           txtEU.focus();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
      //aspcode
 <asp:ImageButton ID="button" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Myfunction();" ImageUrl="/myfolder/abc.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#<%= yourtextboxname.ClientID %>').val() =="")
  // String is not empty
}
```