# finding the first empty input box

Tags: php, html

I have many input fields and I need to ascertain the first empty input field. at the moment I'm checking each one individually and if its not empty move on to the next one. But I was wondering if anyone knew of a more efficient way of doing this:

```
if(empty($a)){$a=$name;}else
if(empty($b)){$b=$name;}else
if(empty($c)){$c=$name;}else 

............if(empty($z)){$z=$name;}else

{$message="all boxes are filled"};
```

Comment: Can you move `$a`, `$b`, and `$c` into a single array?

Comment: You can use JQuery. There is a similar thread. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502354/textbox-empty-check-using-javascript

Comment: This would be a perfect scenario for a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming you're using `POST` or `GET` on the form you can just loop through each form element as such:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { }
```

Comment: I tried that but I could only make find all empty ones, not just the first empty one

Comment: @user1559811 Use the `break;` keyword when you get a match there, so it will stop looping.